# Android: How to update specific line of text file

Tags: java, android, file, text

does anyone has idea on how to code this:

I have a text file with contents (4 lines):

```
1 I am Kris
2 I live in CA
3 With my wife
4 And son
```

Then I want to update the second line `I live in CA` to `I live in New York`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way just to read whole file, modify lines and write back.

You can try [RandomAccessFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) class, but I think it will be overhead. You'll need to do more work and it will be harder to implement.